# What's the maximum number of characters permitted for the password of a Google Account?

Tags: google-account, passwords

What's the maximum length of characters permitted for a Google Account's password?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum size is 100 characters.

FYI, the minimum is 8.

---

[image: Proof]

Comment: What is the sense of limiting password's maximum length? Passwords are (or at least should be) stored at hashes which always have a fixed length so what's the point of these 100 chars?

Comment: Here is a document from Steve gibson's security now with a list of the 100 top E retailers https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am6Sf8IL7PUgdERqRmlHUF9aVVVNQnpGbTNodnpKQVE&usp=docslist_api